# My IIS7 URL rewrite rules keep disappearing

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have regular IIS7 rewrite rules -- the SEO ones (canonical name tags, trailing slashes, lowercase letters).  They work fine.

But then a day later, or even a few hours later, they're gone -- as if they were never there in the first place, so I have to redo them again in IIS7.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening, and what I should do?  Thanks!

Comment: Is anything updating your web.config file?  Not accidentally redeploying over it??

Comment: I feel dumb now.  You were correct.  Thanks for taking the time, Hightech, to respond to my question.

Comment: An easy mistake to make (I know!) ... made it an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check that there isn't something else that's updating your web.config file.

Accidentally redeploying over it can cause this to happen since IIS stores the rewrite rules in your web.config file.

Comment: You were correct, hightech ... I was adjusting my web.config without paying attention to the rewrite rules.  Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question!